# How can I repeat my entire slideshow?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

The title says it all. How can I make my slideshow loop continuously in Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 for Windows?

Comment: 'Loop slide show until  'Esc'' in the set up my slide show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft PowerPoint:

1. Click the **Slideshow** tab
2. Click the button labelled **Set Up Slide Show**
3. A window will appear with a number of advanced settings for your slide show: There will be a checkbox under *Show options* section labelled **Loop continuously until 'Esc'** - check this
4. Click **OK** to confirm the setting

   ---

   After you have done this you may run your slide show and when you ever want to exit just press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button (usually at the top left of your keyboard).

*That's all*

Comment: Can we get detailed instructions on how to do this?  I personally know how to do this others might not.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited it. Sorry I was in a rush last time.